# UICollectionView Strange gap between cells (Swift)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to display 2 sections of images in columns of 3. For some reason, there are these strange gaps between some of the cells. I've looked everywhere in my storyboard and everything seems correct. I've also experimented with setting the columns to 2, 4, 5, 6, and so on. There are no strange white lines with the columns set to any other number. These lines appear both in the 5S simulator and on my physical iPhone 5S.

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView!.frame) / 3
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}
```

Comment: Which device are you testing on? I'm not experiencing any gap on Simulator with your project

Comment: Good point. It looks like it only happens on a 5S. It's happening on my 5S in the Simulator and on my physical device.

Comment: Questions on SO must be self-contained. Please don't just link to your entire project: put the necessary pieces here, in the post. See: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work; can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Comment: @kylesureline Indeed, there is an issue. Did you try to implement `UIViewController` subclass instead of `UICollectionViewController`? I never use `UICollectionViewController` and `UITableViewController` because they incorporate many bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This error is being caused by the floating point calculation you did for `width`.

An iPhone 5S has 320 pixels on its width. Assuming your `collectionView` has the same width as the screen, the width and height of each cell would be `320 / 3 = 106.666666667`, which is a repeating decimal.

To fix this, I'd recommend using a number divisible by 3, and smaller than (and very close to) 320 for your `collectionView` width. So if you use 318, the resulting width and height of each cell would be `318 / 3 = 106`, which is a nice number!

**General Rule**: UICollectionView width should be divisible by the number of cells in each row.